# How do I make en/em dashes work in Myriad when using it with MinionPro

Tags: fonts, captions, punctuation, sans-serif, minionpro

I'm using MinionPro for the body of a document and Myriad for figure/table captions. Because I can't load packages MinionPro and Myriad at the same time, I load the Myriad fonts for the sans-serif fonts using a `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\Myriad-LF}` call in the preamble. Then I set the figure/table captions to use the sans-serif font using package `caption`.

This works great, except that the en dashes (`--`) and em dashes (`---`) are not properly interpreted as long dashes; they're displayed as two or three hyphens. A minimal working example is below. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Set fonts (Minion Pro, Myriad):
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro} % 'lf' option to use full-height (lining) figures

% We can't use package Myriad here as it conflicts with MinionPro, so
% instead we declare the Myriad fonts manually.
% Set body sans serif (\textsf) text to Myriad with lining figures:
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{Myriad-LF}

% Set math sans serif (\mathsf) alphabet to Myriad with lining figures:
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{normal}{OML}{Myriad-LF}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OML}{Myriad-LF}{b}{n}

\usepackage[margin=10pt,font={small,sf},labelfont={sf,bf},labelsep=endash]{caption}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \ldots
  \caption{The mass of the coal storage piles ranged from 8--20 megatonnes.}
  \label{fig:coal}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This outputs the following, with the incorrect dash highlighted.

[image: mwe image]

Comment: You can use `MinionPro` and `MyriadPro` together! Use the `onlytext` option of `MyriadPro`, which is default in a recent version.

Comment: @sebschub care to provide an answer to take this oldie off the unanswered list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages `MinionPro` and `MyriadPro` from [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) can be used together. By default, the math font is not changed by `MyriadPro`. With the `sansmath` option, the sans serif of `\mathsf` is adjusted and an additional math version is defined to allow two math fonts with matching math symbols in one document (see the [documentation](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/raw/master/doc/MyriadPro.pdf) for that).

Thus, the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Set fonts (Minion Pro, Myriad Pro):
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro} % 'lf' option to use full-height (lining) figures
\usepackage[lf, sansmath, scale=0.91]{MyriadPro}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{sfmath}{\mathversion{sans}}
\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font={small,sf, sfmath},labelfont={sf,bf},labelsep=endash}

\begin{document}

Some text with $a \times \mathsf{b} = c / d$.

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \ldots
  \caption{The mass of the coal storage piles ranged from 8--20
    megatonnes and $a \times b = c / d$.}
  \label{fig:coal}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image: Minion and Myriad in one document]